# How to convert MBR partition to GPT from gdisk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed and i'm trying dual boot with Win 11.
Ubuntu installed on SSD and Win11 goes to HDD, but i tried to convert MBR to GPT following [this](https://explorelinux.com/convert-disk-mbr-to-gpt-on-linux/)

but when i'm in the Windows installation setup still partition identified as MBR,

```
pathum@pathum-Inspiron-5593:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for pathum: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
```

how can i convert this partition to GPT completely.

Thanks in advace.

```
pathum@pathum-Inspiron-5593:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
[sudo] password for pathum: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

Comment: You want GPT (and UEFI mode) anywhere, that must be stated in no uncertain terms. But for the purpose of installing Windows in UEFI mode, a must for Windows 11, only the target drive must be GPT. And don't install any modern OS in a HDD. Windows 11 in particular will be so slow to the point it'll be almost unusable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for response, is it safe to create partitions on SSD,

Comment: It depends. Managing partitions always has a data loss risk. Depending on the specific operations the degree of risk varies. Extending is usually very low risk. Shrinking has an higher risk but still on the low side provided you keep an healthy amount of free space. Moving has a much higher risk. So 1. make sure you have backups and 2. Do NOT create partitions for Windows or any OS you want to install in dual-boot, just make sure you can get enough unallocated space and unallocated space is not a partition, the OS installer will then create it or more than one as it sees fit.

Comment: Your `gdisk`-output shows clearly that the disk is GPT (`GPT: present`). It also shows protective MBR (`MBR: protective`) which belongs to GPT, this is not old msdos format, it's GPT. So you converted succesfully, nothing else to do.

Comment: @mook765 but when windows setup disk detected as MBR and cannot go forward

Comment: @pl-jay Then you either choose the wrong disk to install to or you provided output for the wrong disk. Oh, I see, you provided output for `/dev/sda1` which indeed should look different. You should show output for `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to convert the wrong device. From your first output:

```
~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for pathum: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
```

This is how your output from `sudo gdisk /dev/sda1` should look like:

```
~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for mook: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

**What happened to your partition `sda1`? Is it still good?**

You wrote a GPT partition table to your partition `sda1`. If the partition was formatted with a filesystem, the file system is most likely corrupted since the partition table is written to the first sectors of the partition, that's where normally the filesystem's superblock resides. The superblock holds detailed information about the filesystem. This can easily be fixed by reformatting the partition. If you had personal data stored on this partition, you have a headache now, you would need to repair the filesystem using appropriate tools or need to use data recovery software.

**How can I convert my disk to GPT then?**

You need to convert the whole drive `/dev/sda`, so you have to run `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` and then use the `w`-command in gdisk to write the GPT partition table to the disk, then use command `q` to exit gdisk. This will convert your disk to GPT.

The [guide you followed](https://explorelinux.com/convert-disk-mbr-to-gpt-on-linux/) is wrong in this point, it is not a single partition which is MBR or GPT, it is the whole drive which is MBR or GPT.

**Limitations**

On a GPT disk, the first 34 sectors of the disk are reserved for the protective MBR, the GPT header and the partition table. The last 33 sectors are reserved for a backup of the GPT header and the partition table.Before convertin, you should make sure, that the first 34 and last 33 sectors of the disk are not used by any partition. A useful command to check this `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

**Reminder**

Make double sure, that `/dev/sda` is really the disk you want to convert. The command `lsblk -f` should give you sufficient overview about your disks and partitions.